# What should define the scope of a RESTful webservice?

Tags: web-services, rest

I have a web system for the purchasing and selling of coupons, which is served through a RESTful web service. There are 2 client mobile apps which consume this service, one is to allow users to browse and purchase coupons, and the other is for merchants to publish coupons. It felt like a single web service since they are operating on the same data, however I'm wondering whether or not that is the correct criteria for defining the scope of a web service. I'm feeling that maybe it should be more to do with "serving a particular type of client", since the way the data is queryed and how it is returned is different, am I right in my suspicions?

So this made me wonder what should define the scope a given web service? This isn't supposed to be an opinionated question, since it feels like there should be quite concrete qualities with their justifications as to what should define the scope and cohesiveness of a given web service.

And more importantly (for me!), what should I do in my instance? If in my example it should in fact be 2 web services, then what is the correct way of differentiating them when being served by the same provider? Serving each from a different subdomain?

i.e `user.xxx.com` and `merchant.xxx.com`

or is it considered un-RESTful to seperate them based on different directories:

i.e `api.xxx.com/user` and `api.xxx.com/merchant`

The latter would involve purchasing a wildcard SSL certificate unfortunately but damn the expense!

Would really appreciate some assurance as to how to proceed to not dig myself in to a hole =)

Answer (score 0):

> There are 2 client mobile apps which consume this service, one is to allow users to browse and purchase coupons, and the other is for merchants to publish coupons. It felt like a single web service since **they are operating on the same data**, however I'm wondering whether or not that is the correct criteria for defining the scope of a web service. I'm feeling that maybe it should be more to do with "serving a particular type of client", since the way the data is queryed and how it is returned is different, am I right in my suspicions?

The part in bold is what should tell you the answer.

If you'd split up the webservice in 2, you'd expose yourself to two major problems, namely

- Duplicate data. Having the same data for 2 services in 2 different places.
- Need to sync the data between the services. This may be doable but is really not something you want to spend your time on.

Therefore I would say that one 'heap' of data used by multiple apps should simply go in one webservice.

Whether you use `user.api.xxx.com` or `api.xxx.com/user` doesn't really matter. It only defines the root endpoint for the service, it's of no importance as far as REST goes.

---

> the data would still be residing in a single place, in the same database, in the same system etc, so there wouldn't be any duplication. I would just be providing two different web services (i.e interfaces) to the same backend system for the purposes of serving the data differently for different types of client.

I would still use one service. Different types of clients (regular users & merchants) can authenticate themselves to tell the service which resources they are authorized (= allowed) to read and/or manipulate.

This is a common practice in webservices. Same data but different people with different functions accessing that data. Authorization was made for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Let me just clarify something to see if it effects your answer.

Even if I were to provide two web services the data would still be residing in a single place, in the same database, in the same system etc, so there wouldn't be any duplication. I would just be providing two different web services (i.e interfaces) to the same backend system for the purposes of serving the data differently for different types of client.

Comment: Regarding user.api.xxx.com or api.xxx.com/user, if both are common practise then will go with second since it saves me a buck(!), was just wondering whether the 2nd was considered more "RESTful".